# Builder (android.content.Context) in Builder cannot be applied to (anonymous android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener)

Tags: android, dialog, android-dialog

I have this problem:

```
Builder
(android.content.Context)
in Builder cannot be applied
to
(anonymous android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener)
```

on the this code:

```
AlertDialog ventana;
    ventana=new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
    ventana.setTitle("COBARDE");
    ventana.setMessage("Rendidse es de debiles,a seguir jugando");
    ventana.show();
    ventana.setButton(8,"Confirmar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogo1, int id) {
            aceptar();
        }
        public void aceptar(){
            AlertDialog ventana2;
            ventana2=new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
            ventana2.setTitle("puto");
            ventana2.setMessage("Rendidse es de debiles,a seguir jugando");
            ventana2.show();
        }

    });
```

can someone solve that?i am trying to put an alert dialog inside of another alert dialog

Comment: you might want to pass the activity instance.. right now you are passing listener.. did you try MainActivity.this instead of this?

Comment: uh,it works ,thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

Instead of `this` (which is passing an instance of listener) please use `MainActivity.this` 
(or whatever the name of your activity is)